# ASP.NET Gridview and SEO friendly paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging, seo

I've started a topic (http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/7571-Xslt-paging-vs-UserControl-gridview) a while ago about the default ASP.NET Gridview vs XSLT paging. The conclusion was that XSLT paging should be used if you can because it's SEO friendly.

In some situations I need to use the ASP.NET Gridview, but I'd like to make the paging SEO friendly. Is there a good solution for this? I use the default paging options of the Gridview. I though about passing the page in a querystring and set this value to the pageindex of the Gridview. Will that work?

Thanks,

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Try using datalist and do your custom paging by adding querystring for the page